# Can connect socket in Android

Tags: android, sockets, client

I'm in a school project trying to connect a android app to a server that give us the hour, but when I try to connect the socket to my app i got an error:

This is the code of the MainActivity.java

```
public void ejecutar(View view) throws UnknownHostException,IOException{


    InetAddress direServidor =InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.68");
    Socket socket=new Socket(direServidor, 1000);
    System.out.println("Si me presionaron");
    InputStream is=socket.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (is));
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fecha);
    et.setText(br.readLine());
    br.close();
    socket.close();

}
```

It is only the function.

I already configured the permissions in manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name= "android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

But nothing seems to work!

Logcat:

```
> 02-19 00:26:27.044: E/AndroidRuntime(16758): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 02-19 00:26:27.044: E/AndroidRuntime(16758): Process:
> com.example.clientehora, PID: 16758 02-19 00:26:27.044:
> E/AndroidRuntime(16758): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not
> execute method of the activity 02-19 00:26:27.044:
> E/AndroidRuntime(16758):  at
> android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823) 02-19 00:26:27.044:
> E/AndroidRuntime(16758):  at
> android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 02-19 00:26:27.044:
> E/AndroidRuntime(16758):  at
> android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 02-19
> 00:26:27.044: E/AndroidRuntime(16758):    at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 02-19
> 00:26:27.044: E/AndroidRuntime(16758):    at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 02-19
> 00:26:27.044: E/AndroidRuntime(16758):    at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 02-19 00:26:27.044:
> E/AndroidRuntime(16758):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 02-19
> 00:26:27.044: E/AndroidRuntime(16758):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-19
> 00:26:27.044: E/AndroidRuntime(16758):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 02-19 00:26:27.044:
> E/AndroidRuntime(16758):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
> 02-19 00:26:27.044: E/AndroidRuntime(16758):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 02-19
> 00:26:27.044: E/AndroidRuntime(16758):    at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 02-19 00:26:27.044:
> E/AndroidRuntime(16758): Caused by:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 02-19 00:26:27.044:
> E/AndroidRuntime(16758):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-19
> 00:26:27.044: E/AndroidRuntime(16758):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 02-19 00:26:27.044:
> E/AndroidRuntime(16758):  at
> android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818) 02-19 00:26:27.044:
> E/AndroidRuntime(16758):  ... 11 more 02-19 00:26:27.044:
> E/AndroidRuntime(16758): Caused by:
> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 02-19 00:26:27.044:
> E/AndroidRuntime(16758):  at
> android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
> 02-19 00:26:27.044: E/AndroidRuntime(16758):  at
> libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84) 02-19
> 00:26:27.044: E/AndroidRuntime(16758):    at
> libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127) 02-19
> 00:26:27.044: E/AndroidRuntime(16758):    at
> libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112) 02-19 00:26:27.044:
> E/AndroidRuntime(16758):  at
> java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192) 02-19
> 00:26:27.044: E/AndroidRuntime(16758):    at
> java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) 02-19
> 00:26:27.044: E/AndroidRuntime(16758):    at
> java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:567) 02-19 00:26:27.044:
> E/AndroidRuntime(16758):  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:226)
> 02-19 00:26:27.044: E/AndroidRuntime(16758):  at
> com.example.clientehora.MainActivity.ejecutar(MainActivity.java:37)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your socket in a separate thread, off the main thread in order to complete this operation. Reason being doing this kind of heavy activity on the main thread might lock up the app and and cause it to crash.

```
public void ejecutar(View view) throws UnknownHostException,IOException{
    new Thread( new Runnable(){
        InetAddress direServidor = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.68");
        Socket socket = new Socket(direServidor, 1000);
        System.out.println("Si me presionaron");
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (is));
        EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fecha);
        et.setText(br.readLine());
        br.close();
        socket.close();
   }).start();
 }
```

Give that a spin.

Comment: I think that might be the problem! But I cant understand how to do it in Java and Android. Can you give me a example or something?